# SQL match comma separated strings

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm wondering how to perform the following select query in PHP/MySQL.

The MySQL field is called `'types'` and contains values like this: `Provincie\,Gebied\,Water\` or `Water\,Plaats\`

Then in PHP, I receive a string that's formatted like this: `$types = 'Plaats, Provincie, Gebied, Water'`

What I would like to do is select every row that contains at least one of the values that's in the PHP array.

Any Thoughts about the best way to do this?

**Edit**
I can't add another table to the DB, although it would be a nice option.

Which doesn't return any columns is this:

```
$types = explode(',', $types);
    $typesSQL = '';
    foreach($types as $type){
        $type = str_replace(' ', '', $type);
        $typesSQL .= "FIND_IN_SET('$type', types) OR ";
    }
    $typesSQL = substr($typesSQL, 0, -3);
SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."ttr_results WHERE user_id = $user_id AND area = '$area' AND content = '$content' AND ($typesSQL) ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Comment: Normalise and restructure your database to provide a 1-many relation between your existing table and a new types table

Comment: Well, that's the problem. I would prefer that too, but it isn't a real option for this project, can't add a new table.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the `find_in_set()` [MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Thanks, I did. But FIND_IN_SET takes only a single string as argument, in fact I have would like to find any of the substrings in the string $types = 'Plaats, Provincie'

Comment: Ah yep, didn't see at first read that you had multiple values to check.
Doing the filtering in PHP is out of the question as you'll have too much processing to do for big resultset. 
IMO Better option is what @mark-baker suggested : if you can do it, extract your types in a dedicated table

Comment: I did saw that comment. But onfortunalty I didn't have the option to create anothe table. Editing the existing table would be a option though I don't see how that could help, since the number of types to store varies.